# Should I check NODE_MODULE_VERSION or V8_MAJOR_VERSION/V8_MINOR_VERSION?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, v8, node-nan

I'm working on a native module for Node.js and I see that there's two ways to check which V8 version it's being run on:

```cpp
#if (V8_MAJOR_VERSION < 9 || (V8_MAJOR_VERSION == 9 && V8_MINOR_VERSION < 4))
```

or

```cpp
#if defined NODE_MODULE_VERSION && NODE_MODULE_VERSION < 93
```

I like the first way because it doesn't require learning what `NODE_MODULE_VERSION` is and then looking up in two tables (for [Node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases) and [Electron](https://github.com/electron/releases)) to see what it actually means but it's shorter and seems like it might be safer to be less granular. Are there any other considerations over which way to pick?

Comment: Check the variable that expresses the property you care about?